# Apache and Tomcat integration

Tags: apache-httpd, tomcat

I am trying to integrate apache and tomcat. I thus want apache to forward requests to tomcat.
I am using the mod_jk module for apache to achieve this.

So far I am trying to get tomcat to auto-gen the configuration files for the mod_jk - I add the relevant to my server.xml

```
<Listener className="org.apache.jk.config.ApacheConfig" modJk="/usr/lib/apache2/modules/mod_jk.so" />
```

This does not however work.

Please could someone that has done this recently give me some direction? I suspect that a lot of the documentation is for old versions of apache and tomcat.

Answer (score 1):

Okay, I got it. You have to include the worker.properties before it will generate the mod_jk.conf